# How to create blur effect on uiview in IOS 6 (before setTintColor)

Tags: objective-c, uiview, blur

I found many version of creating blur effect on github but could not find one that works in IOS 6 since there is no tint, my views become blue-tinted I've tried setting the backgroundcolor to various options all resulted in same blue-tinted view

any advice or and link to ready to use blur library?

Answer (score 0):

Try FXBlurView, it's good for me; you can download it https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

it's simple to use!